# GitHub Actions with multiple private submodules

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to create a GH Actions job, which will download two submodules from private repositories. I want them to be downloaded with SSH keys which I have already generated.

I've been trying to it as so:

```
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          submodules: repo_1
          ssh-key: ${{ secrets.REPO_1 }}

      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          submodules: repo_2
          ssh-key: ${{ secrets.REPO_2 }}
```

This code will create the folders of `repo_1` and `repo_2`, but will be empty.
I have not found a possible solution. Does anyone know how to download multiple private submodules with separate SSH keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround:

```
steps:
      - name: Switch to HTTPS git
        run: |
          rm -f ~/.gitconfig
          git config --local --unset url."git@github.com".insteadOf https://github.com || echo "OK"
          git config --local --unset url."git://".insteadOf https:// || echo "OK"

      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Switch to SSH git
        run: |
          git config --local --replace-all url."git@github.com".insteadOf https://github.com
          git config --local --add url."git://".insteadOf https://

      - name: Checkout submodules
        env:
          GIT_SSH_COMMAND: "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
        run: |
          eval `ssh-agent -s`

          echo "${{secrets.REPO_1}}" | ssh-add -
          git submodule update --init repo_1
          ssh-add -D


          echo "${{secrets.REPO_2}}" | ssh-add -
          git submodule update --init repo_2
          ssh-add -D

          eval `ssh-agent -k`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}
          submodules: recursive
```

You will need to [create an encrypted secret](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/creating-and-using-encrypted-secrets) called `GH_PAT` to store the [personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens). This token will need (at minimum) read-only access to the "Contents" category of the main repository and of all the submodules.

I tested this with the v3 of the Checkout action, but I think it will work with v2 as well.

[Relevant documentation](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/checkout#checkout-multiple-repos-private)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation mentions:

```
# Whether to checkout submodules: `true` to checkout submodules or `recursive` to
    # recursively checkout submodules.
    #
    # When the `ssh-key` input is not provided, SSH URLs beginning with
    # `git@github.com:` are converted to HTTPS.
    #
    # Default: false
    submodules: ''
```

So `submodules: repo_2` should not be correct.

For instance, this is a workflow with a recursive checkout of submodules (inside an existing repository reference)

```yaml
      # Submodules recursive
      - name: Checkout submodules recursive
        uses: ./
        with:
          ref: test-data/v2/submodule-ssh-url
          path: submodules-recursive
          submodules: recursive
      - name: Verify submodules recursive
        run: __test__/verify-submodules-recursive.sh
```

It will checkout the repo [`github.com/actions/checkout` branch `test-data/v2%2Fsubmodule-ssh-url`](https://github.com/actions/checkout/tree/test-data/v2%2Fsubmodule-ssh-url), which includes a [`.gitmodules`](https://github.com/actions/checkout/blob/test-data/v2/submodule-ssh-url/.gitmodules) with the names and SSH URL of the submodules.

To answer your original question:

- change your .gitmodules URL with

```
repo1:org1/repo1
repo2:org2/repo2
```

- Add GIT_SSH_COMMAND environment variable to `ssh -F config`, with `config` being a file with:

```
Host repo2
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile key2

Host repo2
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile key2
```

I don't know if it is possible to reference that file, generated with the right `secrets.REPO_x`, but what I can see from the checkout action is that you won"t have a native way to specify multiple keys for multiple submodule repositories.

Comment: It doesn't really answer the question. Beside the incorrect usage of `submodules:` you didn't provide an answer on how to download multiple submodules from private repositories.

Comment: @This-is-patriiick I have edited the answer to address your question.

Comment: Doing so, I get an error: `Error: fatal: repository 'https://github.com/org/second-repo/' not found`

Comment: @This-is-patriiick And I suppose you have replaced org and second repo by the right value? The doc specifies that if ssh-key is not provided, the URL is changed into an HTTPS one. Is ssh-key properly declared and valued?

Comment: that is correct. The `org` and `second-repo` are replaced with the correct values. The urls to the submodules inside the `.gitmodules` are written as `git@github.com:org/second-repo.git`

Comment: @This-is-patriiick I did not see a solution to do one checkout with submodule recursive clone, using two different keys. I have edited the answer to suggests a possible option to explore.